# Php decode function for an encode function

Tags: php

I have an encode function in php and I tried to make a decode function for it but I didn't succced.. Can someone help me with this?

```
function encode($data)
{

    $password = 'EBuLTKjdCf0dmX7MQ1SrquKtvs7Fn5EW13xouUNGWwpqLWisMqe8v574HWS1UT2bkAMXC163euCz5MDm0U2GpuY';
    $salt = substr(md5(mt_rand(), true), 8);
    $key = md5($password . $salt, true);
    $iv = md5($key . $password . $salt, true);
    $ct = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $unique = md5(mt_rand(), true);
    return str_replace(array('+', '/'), array('-', '_'), rtrim(base64_encode($unique . $salt . $ct), '='));
}

function decode($data) {


    $password = 'EBuLTKjdCf0dmX7MQ1SrquKtvs7Fn5EW13xouUNGWwpqLWisMqe8v574HWS1UT2bkAMXC163euCz5MDm0U2GpuY';
    $salt = $data = base64_decode( str_replace( array( '-', '_' ), array( '+', '/' ), $data ) );
    $ct = substr( $data, 18 );
    md5( $password . $salt, true );
    $key = substr( $data, 10, 8 );

    $iv = md5( $key . $password . $salt, true );
    $pt = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ct, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv );
    return trim( $pt);
}
```

Decode function return a null string.

Comment: hashing is one way

Comment: Rather than developing own function have a look over here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php php already provides support for them :)

Comment: *mcrypt* is **abandomware**, depreciated in PHP 7.1 and possibly removed in PHP 7.2

Comment: This definitely is NOT a hashing algorithm.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: The encryption is not very secure, at a minimum: 1. The key should be derived from the password with a function similar to PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2) with an iteration of ~100ms. 2. the IV should be obtained from a CPRNG (Cryptographic Pseudo Random Number Generator) and generally prepended to the encrypted data. 3. Generally use PKCS#7 padding (mcrypt does not support this standard) so that the input data can be any length, not restricted in length to a multiple of the block size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
function decode($data) {
    $password = 'EBuLTKjdCf0dmX7MQ1SrquKtvs7Fn5EW13xouUNGWwpqLWisMqe8v574HWS1UT2bkAMXC163euCz5MDm0U2GpuY';
    $decoded = base64_decode( str_replace( array( '-', '_' ), array( '+', '/' ), $data ) );
    $unique = substr($decoded, 0, 36);
    $salt = substr($decoded, 16, 8);
    $ct = substr($decoded, 24);
    $key = md5($password . $salt, true);
    $iv = md5($key . $password . $salt, true);
    $pt = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ct, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv );

    return trim( $pt);
}
```

E.g.:

```
php > echo decode(encode("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```